# How to check SSD/HDD model used on a VPS?

Tags: server, 16.04, hardware, storage

Is there anyway we can check what is the model of storage device used on VPS without having access to the hypervisor. I`ve tried to check it on DigitalOcean droplet using several command but I didnt get it.

Im running Ubuntu 16.04 btw.

Comment: I assume this will be impossible as your VPS surely is a virtual machine and does not run directly on the hardware. It will only know the details the VM host emulates. However you could try and look how your (virtual?) disk is called (using `lsblk`, the result should be e.g. `/dev/sda`) and check the available info on that using `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda`.

Answer (score 0):

SSD disks are automatically detected, and you may verify this with:

```
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational
```

If it's `1` it's a hard disk and if `0` it's a SSD.